# DOM を変更せずに ajax 送信時にパラメータを追加したい

Tags: javascript, jquery

Rails で作ったフォームのサブミット時に
JS 上に動的にもってるデータを追加して送信したいです

https://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/
これでできそうな気がしたんですが

```
$( document ).ajaxSend(function() {
  console.log('ajaxSend');
});
```

とかいても console.log が表示されません

```
$('form').on("ajax:beforeSend", (event) => {
  console.log(event);
}
```

```
document.getElementById('test_form').addEventListener('ajax:before', (event) => {
   console.log(event);
})
```

とかけば送信前にトリガーはできるんですが event 内にパラメータらしきものがみあたらないので
どうやってパラメータを追加すればいいかわからない状態です

トリガー内で hidden_fiels を追加してそこに値をうめこんで
あとはフォームに任せればできなくはないんですが
諸事情で DOM 側を変更したくないです

jquery 3.6.0 ですが native JS でもいいです
よろしくお願いします

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOMを変更しないとなると、[`FromData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/FormData)を使うのが妥当かと思います。方法は2通り思い浮かびます。

●「[form 要素に紐づけた FormData を使用する](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript#using_formdata_bound_to_a_form_element)」にあるように、`<form>`から`FormData`オブジェクトを作り、そこにパラメータを追加して、XHR でフォーム送信します。
通常のフォームのようにページ遷移はしないので、ページを切り替えたい場合は自力でなんとかする必要があります。

●`formdata` イベントを使います。

```js
form.addEventLiseter('formdata', e => {
  e.formData.append('param1', 'data1');
});
```

フォームは通常通り送信されて、ページ遷移も通常通り起きます。

IEとSafariは未対応です。

Comment: ありがとうございます！　ただ IE はともかく safari で使えないのは困るので大人しくDOMを追加することにします

Comment: 1つ目の●はSafariでも動きます。